# In R, why are 1:n-1 ; 1:(n-1) different?

Tags: r, operator-precedence

I am a beginner in R. I was wondering why `1:n-1` `1:(n-1)` would come out different output?

```
n = 4
1:n-1
[1]0 1 2 3
```

```
n = 4
1:(n-1)
[1]1 2 3
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `:` takes the advantage over `-` thus brackets are required to first perform a substraction

Comment: Operator precedence - `:` has higher precedence than `-` (as a binary operator).

Comment: That's a pitfall you have to be wary of.  `:` has (higher) precedence over `-`  . So  `1:n-1` will first create a vector `1,2,3..n` then subtract 1 from it . Be careful to use parentheses wherever you want  want `(n-1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is related to the precedence of operators in R (see https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html)

[image]

As we can see, `:` has higher precedence than `+-` (add, substract), that means
`1:n-1` is actually `(1:n)-1`, which is definitely different from `1:(n-1)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `n-1` into brackets if you want it to be evaluated first, as `:` is binding stronger than `-`. `1:n-1` evaluates `1:n` first and then subtracts 1 from each element.

In your example, `1:n` yields

````
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Subtraction by 1 yields:

```
[1] 0 1 2 3
```
````